# Notepad++ find and replace using wild card

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have this very long file with many lines like this:

```
MeshFile=brosm05028.gmt CollTarget=True HATTarget=True LODOut=(500.0)
```

What I am trying to do is to use notepad++ find and replace to set the *CollTarget* to False of every MeshFile named *brosm[XXXXX].gmt*. The line of text should end up looking like this:

```
MeshFile=brosm05028.gmt CollTarget=False HATTarget=True LODOut=(500.0)
```

I know how to use ".*" to find but I don't know how to keep the unique numbers when I replace.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: regex101.com is a useful site where you can test regular expressions. The flavour that NP++ uses is "PCRE (PHP <7.3)" IIRC.

Comment: What type of character is `[XXXXX]`? Only numeric, alphanum, other? Is it always 5 characters?

Comment: @Gantendo: Not really, Npp uses boost regex flavour. There are some differences comparing to PCRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep part of the text you find in the replacement intact, you would use [capture groups](https://riptutorial.com/notepadplusplus/example/27189/referencing-capture-groups).

Find (with RegEx):

```
(MeshFile=brosm.*.gmt CollTarget=)(True)
```

And replace with:

```
\1False
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the one, Many thanks, you are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

A more specific regex here would be:

```
^(MeshFile=brosm\d{5}\.gmt CollTarget=)True
```

Explantation:

- `^` to ensure start of the line, if needed
- `\d{5}` to capture 5 digits, which you specified as required file format in your question. If instead you meant any number of digits, then `\d+` can be used.
- `\.` escapes the dot just in case
- everything between `()` gets captured as `\1` and thus you can replace with:

```
\1False
```

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `MeshFile=brosm.+?\.gmt CollTarget=\KTrue`
- Replace with: `False`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
MeshFile=brosm          # literally
.+?                     # 1 or more any character but newline
\.gmt CollTarget=       # literally
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
True                    # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]